# Set HttpOnly Cookies while developing Web App locally

Tags: node.js, angular, cookies, cross-domain

I am developing a web app with angular + nebular auth. Nebular auth is working and I get a JWT token from our auth server. The auth server is made with Node and sets also an HTTPOnly cookie for the refresh token. I want this token to be send along every request.
The login response has indeed the Set-Cookie header, but the cookie is never set. I have read a lot of answers in Stack Overflow but everything I tried did not work.

The auth server is in a Cloud server, while I am developing the app locally. This maybe can be a problem already.

Anyway, here's what I have done till now:

Node.js

I am using an HTTP server, and setting the cookie with cookie-parser with:

```
res.cookie("refresh_token", token, {httpOnly: true, maxAge: ....});
```

I set the core options in app.js like this:

```
app.use(cors({
 credentials: true,
 origin: ["http://localhost:4200", "http://127.0.0.1:4200"]
 exposedHeaders = ["Content-Length", .....],
 allowedHeaders = ["Content-Type", "Authorization", "Set-Cookie", ....],
}));
```

When I get the response of the Login, I do get the Set-Cookie header but I cannot see the cookie in the Cookies tab of my browser console.

I tried to send a request from Angular anyway, with `{ headers: headers, withCredentials: true }` but obviously when I check the cookie in Node there's nothing.

So I am going crazy... it's probably a problem with CORS, because I am developing from localhost and the server is up on the cloud?

How can I make this work?

Comment: Did you try running the application on https instead of http? I had a similar problem (though with a .net server) and running on https solved it.

Comment: I am having problems running in HTTPS at the moment with self signed certificates. Every request I try I get ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: Is this a b2b request between a server and your auth server? If so you may need to make sure your server trusts the self signed certificate as well

Comment: If this is an error you get from a client request your browser might not support self signed certificates (chrome has a problem with those) there's an explanation here about how to bypass that: https://serverfault.com/questions/973446/self-signed-ssl-i-created-for-localhost-cannot-be-trusted-even-though-i-have-alr

Comment: It works when I run everything on my local machine. Seems like it is a problem because I am trying to set a cookie on a client (localhost), from a cloud server (that has an IP and no domain)

Comment: Try running chrome with the --ignore-certificate-errors flag. If the problem happens only on development because of the self signed certificates it should help. Anyway this doesn't sound like a cloud problem

Comment: Hey @GiammarcoBoscaro did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @NikitasIO yes I did. I just posted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the initial solution I have found was just simply running the Node server on localhost. The server was pretty light so no problem but it wasn't the best solution.

I solved the problem with a simple local proxy in Angular:

I created `proxy.json` on the root of the workdir

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://<server_ip>:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Then added this line on `angular.json`

```
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "proxyConfig": "proxy.json", // Added this
    "ssl": false
  },
  ...
```

I also needed to create an HttpInterceptor to intercept http requests and add the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header to every one of them. Usually I use an Interceptor also to add custom headers I need for my project, handle authorization headers and also call the refresh token API when auth tokens are expired. Anyway the simplest Interceptor is this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

/** Inject With Credentials into the request */
@Injectable()
export class HttpRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    
      req = req.clone({
        withCredentials: true
      });
      
      return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Finally on my `environment.ts`

```
export const environment = {
  app_name: "<app_name_dev>",
  production: false,
  api_path: 'http://localhost:4200/api',
};
```

So now using `environment.api_path` as base path to call my authentication APIs works correctly with CORS and I get my HTTP Only Cookie.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Turns out my problem went a bit deeper as it had to do with [creating a custom HttpInterceptor to handle 'withCredentials'](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Apr/07/Creating-a-custom-HttpInterceptor-to-handle-withCredentials) and configuring my **'Access-Control' headers** in my Node.js API.

Comment: oh sure, you need that also. I already put that a long time ago because I needed an interceptor for my authentication system and for Hasura. So I totally forgot it was needed also for this problem. I'll edit my answer